# Smartphone app for JVC Adixxion

Tags: action-cam

For JVC Adixxion, there is "ADIXXION sync." app, available for Android and iOS devices. The app's page states, that it is dedicated to JVC GC-XA2.

Will this app work also with GC-XA1 model? Are there any limitations, or features, that would not work with XA1?

Comment: You could try it and see, but I'd assume that if it is designed to work with the XA2, it is unlikely to work with a previous model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"ADIXXION sync." does not work wit XA1.

However, another app, WiVideo works with XA1. It is available for Android and iOS. For PC, the camera comes with Windows version of WiVideo.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out.  Thanks for updating with the answer.